# SSRS Oracle data date parameter does not show data

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have query from Oracle for making a report, but I get the `ORA-01036` error. How to fix this error?

```
SELECT *
FROM qapsl.T00TESTSETPRODINFO a, qapsl.T00SET_FLEXMACHINEJOIST b, qapsl.T00SPEC_FLEXMACHINEJOIST c
WHERE a.setid = b.setid  
  AND b.Setid = C.setid
  AND ((:DateType = 'Prod' and manufdate between :DateFrom and :DateTo)
       OR  
       (:DateType = 'Test' and TestDate between :DateFrom and :DateTo))
```

Comment: ORA-01036 is about "variable binding", are you sure that when calling this query the variables ":DateType", ":DateFrom" and ":DateTo" are always been passed to the query?